# Передача параметров Json из файла в Bash

Tags: json, bash, xmlhttprequest

Добрый день. Необходимо получить файлы конфигурации Zabbix. Посылаю HTTP запрос из Bash скрипта. Если указать в параметрах ID хостов прямо, используя переменную testid, то все работает. Если же указывать переменную hostid, которая берет из файла те же самые символы, то получаю ответ с ошибкой Json'а. Лишних пробелов в начале и в конце нет. Прошу, натолкните где копать)

```
hostids=$(cat /var/lib/test/ids.txt)
testid=\"10231\",\"10713\"
curl -sS -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"configuration.export\", \"params\":{\"options\":{\"hosts\":[$testid]},\"format\": \"json\"}, \"id\": 1, \"auth\": \"$token\"}" $zbxAPI -o /var/lib/test/conf_hosts.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо было открыть поток, решается так:

```
read hostids</var/lib/test/ids.txt
curl -sS -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json-rpc' -d "{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"method\": \"configuration.export\", \"params\":{\"options\":{\"hosts\":[\"$hostids]},\"format\": \"json\"}, \"id\": 1, \"auth\": \"$token\"}" $zbxAPI -o /var/lib/test/repo/zabbix_conf/conf_hosts.json
```